# Mentalis Security Socket Library Connection Closed

Tags: c#, security, ssl

I have been using [Org.Mentalis Security Socket Library](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/ssocket/), because I read It here somewhere that It's pretty reliable and works well.

No problems at all, the certification gets verified, the connection is live but when I try to write to the stream the connection quickly dies.

```
s.Send(intBytes, 0, intBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
```

> [1/10/2016 1:40:34 AM] [STATUS] ex: Org.Mentalis.Security.SecurityException: An error occurs while communicating with the remote host.
>   Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.Shared.SslException: An error occurred during the decryption and verification process.
>     at Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.Shared.RecordLayer.UnwrapMessage (Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.Shared.RecordMessage message) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.Shared.RecordLayer.ProcessBytes (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.Shared.SocketController.OnReceive (IAsyncResult ar) [0x00000] in :0  ---> Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.Shared.SslException: An error occurred during the decryption and verification process.
>     at Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.Shared.RecordLayer.UnwrapMessage (Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.Shared.RecordMessage message) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.Shared.RecordLayer.ProcessBytes (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.Shared.SocketController.OnReceive (IAsyncResult ar) [0x00000] in :0 
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.SecureSocket.EndReceive (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.SecureSocket.Receive (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) [0x00000] in :0

Has anyone experienced this problem before with that lib?

[The error throw is over here, but I don't exactly know what is that.](https://github.com/sensepost/Suru/blob/master/3rd%20Party/seclib-1.0.0/seclib/Security/Ssl/Shared/RecordLayer.cs#L299)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution before... It doesn't support .Net 3.5 or 2.0